# Cannot call Function within Another Function - React.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code in a basic react app

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function genColor() {
  return <div style="#000000">Test</div>;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {this.genColor()}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Calling `genColor` in the App function, but get 
[image]

How am I screwing this up?

Comment: Change to `{genColor()}` or more appropriately, `<genColor />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've created a global function, but you're calling it as if it's a member of App.

So either move the function to the App class, or remove `this.`